# dbDelta not installing database

Tags: plugin-development, database, table, dbdelta

I'm not sure why this isn't running. When I output dbDelta it says that it created the table, but it doesn't.

I think my SQL is valid. Taking everything out between id and UNIQUE KEY results in the table being made, but I don't see the problem with the other lines.

Thanks

```
function email_install () {
   global $wpdb;

   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "table_name_email"; 

   $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

   $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
     email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     page VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     UNIQUE KEY  (id)
   ) ". $charset_collate . ";";

   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
   dbDelta( $sql );

}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is error in sql query. You have defined time as datetime and default value mentioned in current_timestamp. Define time as timestamp. Also specify length of email and page fields.

Corrected query:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, //Change datetime to timestamp
     email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, //Change length
     page VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, //Change length
     UNIQUE KEY  (id)
   ) ". $charset_collate . ";";
```